# AJAX load more posts script out putting nothing, no warnings, no notices, no data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Can anyone tell me why this is outputting nothing.. at all? No errors, no notices. Nada. 
I really need help with this, theres nothing wrong with the SQL details. The codes purpose is too display Mysql data with an AJAX div that loads more posts. If theres anything that could be causing this please post below. Thanks!:)
Source code:

```
 <?php
    /* grab stuff */
    function get_posts($start = 0, $number_of_posts = 5) {
        /* connect to the db */
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('draft2',$connection) or die(mysql_error()); 
        $posts = array();
        /* get the posts */
        $query = "SELECT item_id, username, item_content FROM updates ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT $start,$number_of_posts" or die(mysql_error()); 

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            preg_match("/<p>(.*)<\/p>/",$row['item_content'],$matches);
            $row['item_content'] = strip_tags($matches[1]);
            $posts[] = $row;
        }
        /* return the posts in the JSON format */
        return json_encode($posts);
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  dir="ltr">
<head>



<style type="text/css">
   .style1 {
                                font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
                                background-image: url('images/banner.gif');
                        }
                        .style2 {
                                font-size: x-small;
                                color: #62D7D7;
                        }
                        .style3 {
                                text-align: center;
                        }
                        .style5 {
                                font-size: 12px;
                                font-family: "lucida grande", "tahoma", "verdana", "arial", "sans-serif"
                        }
                .style6 {
    font-family: "lucida grande", "tahoma", "verdana", "arial", "sans-serif";
}
.style7 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: x-small;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #0070B8;
}

        #load-more                  { background-color:#eee; color:#999; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; padding:10px 0; cursor:pointer; }
        #load-more:hover            { color:#666; }
        .activate                   { background:url(loadmorespinner.gif) 140px 9px no-repeat #eee; }

                </style>




    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //when the DOM is ready
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //settings on top
            var initialPosts = <?php echo get_posts(0,$_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>;
            //function that creates posts
            var postHandler = function(postsJSON) {
                $.each(postsJSON,function(i,post) {
                    //post url
                    var postURL = '' + domain + post.post_name;
                    var id = 'post-' + post.ID;
                    //create the HTML
                    $('<div></div>')
                    .addClass('post')
                    .attr('id',id)
                    //generate the HTML
                    .html('<a href="' + postURL + '" class="username">' + post.username + '</a><p class="item_content">' + post.item_content + '<br /><a href="' + postURL + '" class="post-more">Read more...</a></p>')
                    .click(function() {
                        window.location = postURL;
                    })
                    //inject into the container
                    .appendTo($('#posts'))
                    .hide()
                    .slideDown(250,function() {
                        if(i == 0) {
                            $.scrollTo($('div#' + id));
                        }
                    });
                }); 
            };
            //place the initial posts in the page
            postHandler(initialPosts);
            //first, take care of the "load more"
            //when someone clicks on the "load more" DIV
            var start = <?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start']; ?>;
            var desiredPosts = <?php echo $number_of_posts; ?>;
            var loadMore = $('#load-more');
            //load event / ajax
            loadMore.click(function(){
                //add the activate class and change the message
                loadMore.addClass('activate').text('Loading...');
                //begin the ajax attempt
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'jquery-version.php',
                    data: {
                        'start': start,
                        'desiredPosts': desiredPosts
                    },
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(responseJSON) {
                        //reset the message
                        loadMore.text('Load More');
                        //increment the current status
                        start += desiredPosts;
                        //add in the new posts
                        postHandler(responseJSON);
                    },
                    //failure class
                    error: function() {
                        //reset the message
                        loadMore.text('Oops! Try Again.');
                    },
                    //complete event
                    complete: function() {
                        //remove the spinner
                        loadMore.removeClass('activate');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Widget XHTML Starts Here -->
    <div id="posts-container">
        <!-- Posts go inside this DIV -->
        <div id="posts"></div>
        <!-- Load More "Link" -->
        <div id="load-more">Load More</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Widget XHTML Ends Here -->

</body>
</html>
```

I actually have posted this problem before, i know that will get you all angry. But i tried fixing it for a while but im just not as experienced as the people on here so I return. Please dont hate me.

Comment: I am new to this, I relise this and I have clicked the green tick to the best answers. My answer acceptance has not gone up

Comment: That's because it's not updated directly. It's no problem, I was just letting you know. I'm gonna have a look at your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user663049: I think your problem is this line --

```
$query = "SELECT item_id, username, item_content FROM updates ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT $start,$number_of_posts" or die(mysql_error());
```

It should be --

```
$query = "SELECT item_id, username, item_content FROM updates ORDER BY update_time DESC LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $number_of_posts;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

If it displays nothing maybe because of web server configuration. Could you just try to insert at the begining of the PHP block the following, so you may see at least errors and make the debugging

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
?>
```